# Speeding up the query with multiple joins, group by and order by

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlperformance, postgresql-performance

I have a SQL query as:

```
SELECT
title,
(COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)) AS "count_title"

FROM 
B 
INNER JOIN D ON B.app = D.app
INNER JOIN A ON D.number = A.number 
INNER JOIN C ON A.id = C.id 

GROUP BY C.title
ORDER BY count_title DESC
LIMIT 10
;
```

Table D contains 50M records, A contains 30M records, B & C contains 30k records each. Indexes are defined on all columns used in joins, group by, order by.

The query works fine without the order by statement and returns results in around 2-3 sec.

But, with the sorting operation(order by) the query time increases to 10-12 seconds.

I understand the reason behind this, that executor has to traverse all the records for sorting operation and index will hardly help here.

Are there some other ways to speed up this query?

Here is the explain analyze of this query:

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Limit  (cost=974652.20..974652.22 rows=10 width=54) (actual time=2817.579..2825.071 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=974652.20..974666.79 rows=5839 width=54) (actual time=2817.578..2817.578 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: (count(DISTINCT A.id)) DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=974325.65..974526.02 rows=5839 width=54) (actual time=2792.465..2817.097 rows=3618 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: C.title"
"              Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=974325.65..974372.97 rows=18931 width=32) (actual time=2792.451..2795.161 rows=45175 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: C.title"
"                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 5055kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"                    ->  Gather  (cost=968845.30..972980.74 rows=18931 width=32) (actual time=2753.402..2778.648 rows=45175 loops=1)"
"                          Workers Planned: 1"
"                          Workers Launched: 1"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"                          ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=967845.30..970087.64 rows=11136 width=32) (actual time=2751.725..2764.832 rows=22588 loops=2)"
"                                Hash Cond: ((C.id)::text = (A.id)::text)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=120299 read=573195"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on C  (cost=0.00..1945.87 rows=66687 width=32) (actual time=0.017..4.316 rows=56684 loops=2)"
"                                      Buffers: shared read=1279"
"                                ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=966604.55..966604.55 rows=99260 width=9) (actual time=2750.987..2750.987 rows=20950 loops=2)"
"                                      Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 4032kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=120266 read=571904"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=219572.23..966604.55 rows=99260 width=9) (actual time=665.832..2744.270 rows=20950 loops=2)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=120266 read=571904"
"                                            ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=219571.79..917516.91 rows=99260 width=4) (actual time=665.804..2583.675 rows=20950 loops=2)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: ((D.app)::text = (B.app)::text)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=8 read=524214"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on D  (cost=217542.51..895848.77 rows=5126741 width=13) (actual time=661.254..1861.862 rows=6160441 loops=2)"
"                                                        Recheck Cond: ((action_type)::text = ANY ('{10,11}'::text[]))"
"                                                        Heap Blocks: exact=242152"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=3 read=523925"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on D_index_action_type  (cost=0.00..214466.46 rows=12304178 width=0) (actual time=546.470..546.471 rows=12320882 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((action_type)::text = ANY ('{10,11}'::text[]))"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=3 read=33669"
"                                                  ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=1859.36..1859.36 rows=13594 width=12) (actual time=4.337..4.337 rows=16313 loops=2)"
"                                                        Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1152kB"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=5 read=289"
"                                                        ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using B_index_app on B  (cost=0.29..1859.36 rows=13594 width=12) (actual time=0.015..2.218 rows=16313 loops=2)"
"                                                              Heap Fetches: 0"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=5 read=289"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using A_index_number on A  (cost=0.43..0.48 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=41900)"
"                                                  Index Cond: ((number)::text = (D.number)::text)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=120258 read=47690"
"Planning Time: 0.747 ms"
"Execution Time: 2825.118 ms"
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for your query to the question?

Comment: I have added it. @LaurenzAlbe Also, I guess the query was cached, So it executed comparatively fast.

Comment: That execution plan is from a different query. I see `d.action_type IN ('10', '11')` in there.

Comment: Yes, this is an additional condition. But it won't make much difference.

Comment: It makes a difference, because you could try an index only scan on `d` in that case.

Comment: Actually, the condition return 60-70% of records. So, it's not filtering out much records. And I have already defined the index on that column, but it's still going with bitmap-heap scan.

Comment: I am fetching around 30k rows. Is it a big number? Can making multiple index or clusterize help?

Comment: I think I have found a solution; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to aim for a nested loop join between `b` and `d` because `b` is so much smaller:

```
CREATE INDEX ON d (app);
```

If `d` is vacuumed frequently enough, you could see if an index only scan is even faster. For that, include `number` in the index (in v11, use the `INCLUDE` clause for that!). The `EXPLAIN` output suggests that you have an extra condition on `action_type`; you'd have to include that column too for an index only scan.

Comment: Created a covering index: 
`CREATE INDEX d_covering_index ON d(app) INCLUDE(number,action_type)`
Still the executor is going for bitmap heap scan.

Comment: a) did you `VACUUM d`? b) did you try with an index only on `app`?

Comment: Yes. I vacuumed d. The single index on app is also defined.

But still, no change in execution plan.

Comment: Also, after joining A & C, the number of rows are around 80K.

In table D, after applying action_type constraint, the number of records are 4M and 3 loops (using bitmap heap scan). This step is taking most of the execution time.

Comment: Ok, then I can see no hope for making the query faster. You can throw hardware at it (RAM).

Comment: Okay. Thanks anyway. I'll post if I get a new lead.